# Entity Framework Many-to-Many Inserting Fine, But Not Properly Updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Good morning!

I have a many-to-many relationship between the Employee and Skill entities. When I create a new Employee, the Skills that I select are added to the database without a problem. However, when I update an Employee, the Employee content updates, but none of the Skills are added/removed. I see that they are being passed to the repository, but it is not updating the database.

I have the following many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Employee : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class Skill : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

My controller Adds/Removes the Employee's skills through the following method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, EmployeeEditViewModel viewModel)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.SkillsList = _skillService.GetAll().ToList();
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        var employee = Mapper.Map<Employee>(viewModel);

        UpdateSkills(employee, viewModel.NewSkills);

        _employeeService.Update(employee);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
        viewModel.SkillsList = _skillService.GetAll().ToList();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}



    private void UpdateSkills(Employee employee, IEnumerable<int> updatedSkills)
    {
        if (employee.Skills != null)
        {
            var updatedSkillsList = updatedSkills as IList<int> ?? updatedSkills.ToList();
            var addedSkills = updatedSkillsList.Except(employee.Skills.Select(x => x.Id));
            var removedSkills = employee.Skills.Select(x => x.Id).Except(updatedSkillsList);

            addedSkills.ForEach(x => employee.Skills.Add(_skillService.GetById(x)));
            removedSkills.ForEach(x => employee.Skills.Remove(_skillService.GetById(x)));
        }
        else
        {
            employee.Skills = new List<Skill>();
            newSkills.ForEach(x => employee.Skills.Add(_skillService.GetById(x)));
        }
    }
```

The Employee is then inserted/updated with a generic repository:

```
public void Insert(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

    try
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        ThrowValidationError(ex);
    }
}


    public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

        try
        {
            _dbSet.Attach(entity);
            _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            ThrowValidationError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Here is how the Employee object is being called from the data Context.

My constructor:

```
protected readonly NTierApplicationsDataContext _dbContext;
        protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

        public EfRepository(NTierApplicationsDataContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _dbSet = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }
```

Here is the find method to get the object:

```
public TEntity GetById(int id)
        {
            return _dbSet.Find(id);
        }
```

Comment: How do you get the `employee' object? Do you get it from the context? For thus functionality to work, EF will have to activate object Tracking.

Comment: Yes, in my generic repository I call it from the application data context.

Comment: Added the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you must update the employee it self after editing the skills as below

```
private void UpdateSkills(Employee employee, IEnumerable<int> updatedSkills)
{
    if (employee.Skills != null)
    {
        var updatedSkillsList = updatedSkills as IList<int> ?? updatedSkills.ToList();
        var addedSkills = updatedSkillsList.Except(employee.Skills.Select(x => x.Id));
        var removedSkills = employee.Skills.Select(x => x.Id).Except(updatedSkillsList);

        addedSkills.ForEach(x => employee.Skills.Add(_skillService.GetById(x)));
        removedSkills.ForEach(x => employee.Skills.Remove(_skillService.GetById(x)));

         // here 
         _employeeService.Update(employee);
    }
    else
    {
        employee.Skills = new List<Skill>();
        newSkills.ForEach(x => employee.Skills.Add(_skillService.GetById(x)));
    }
}
```

EDIT: Check Mapping

EDIT:

I think that the mapping for your entities has a problem, you can do another approach

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, EmployeeEditViewModel viewModel)
{
   try
   {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        viewModel.SkillsList = _skillService.GetAll().ToList();
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    //here your mapper is not attaching the employee to the context
    //var employee = Mapper.Map<Employee>(viewModel);

    you can do this 
    var employee = _employeeService.GetById(viewModel.Id);
    // after that ... update what the user did from the view model except the id as the id won't change
    employee = Mapper.Map<Employee>(viewModel, employee);
    // I think that the mapping have another overload to map to a destination. you can set the setup for the mappnig in the startup to ignore updating Ids        

    UpdateSkills(viewModel.NewSkills);

    _employeeService.Update(employee);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
    viewModel.SkillsList = _skillService.GetAll().ToList();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

}

Comment: You are correct. That is what I am doing. Sorry, I did not include that in my original post. I have updated the code above.

Comment: Sorry, no. I already had that in place. Like I said, it is updating the Employee content, but not the related data in the many-to-many relationship. I think Ghasan is right about it not activating the object tracking for the related entities, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: I think you can do one thing ... in the update skills ... remove what the user have instead of updating ... and add all from scratch, 'UpdateSkills(Employee e, IEnumerable<int> skills){ e.Skills = new List<Skill>(); skills.ForEach(x=> e.Skills.Add(_skillService.GetById(x))); }'

Comment: No luck. I got the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91072/discussion-between-sherif-ahmed-and-bsmith).